# Accessing calling contract storage in a library

Tags: solidity, contract-development, library

I need to understand how is it possible to access the calling contract storage from library code. From Solidity manual:

> This means that if library functions are called, their code is executed in the context of the calling contract, i.e. this points to the calling contract, and especially the storage from the calling contract can be accessed.

So I'm trying to compile this simple test library:

```
library Test_Lib {
    function test_function()
    public
    returns (bool)
    {
        return (this.owner.send(this.balance));
    }
}
```

But I get the following error:

> Error: Member "owner" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in library Test_Lib

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

If you think about it, the library can not know the variable names of the calling contract. The compiler must fail. What you can do is pass the variable through the interface. In the background, no transaction calls need to be done and the param can be passed by-reference instead of by-value...

Comment: Got it. How would you rewrite it, something like the following?

function test_function(address calling_contract)

Comment: at least upvote me ;-)

Comment: Just did it. Sorry I'm new to this site :)

Comment: yes you pass the address

Comment: I guess I still do some mistake with the syntax of this:
Error: Member "owner" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in address (caller is the argument of the function)
return (caller.owner.send(caller.balance));

Comment: owner is not a solidity thing. its a variable name. `caller.send` is correct. Me still 0 :-(

Comment: Yes "owner" is the variable inside the calling contract I want to access... maybe I think I misunderstood the features of solidity laibraries. Unfortunately it seems I cannot upvote you with < 15 reputation :(

Comment: ok you should not pass the whole calling contract and then do `caller.owner. send...` just pass the freaking `owner` variable as an address and the `balance` as second param